# Code java-script to display Satellite mode by default Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to code java-script to force Google maps to display satellite mode by default instead of road map. If there is I I was unable to find the answer at Google Developers.

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 or http://maps.google.com?

Comment: Google Maps Javascript API v3

Comment: Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Im sory I did not use a more definitive explanation the first go-around, i will try to do better in the future ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set mapTypeId during initialization. Here is a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find more about map types [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes).

Comment: Ah yes! You are my 3rd hero here today, thank ya, thank ya very much ;) I could not find that cause i was looking in the wrong place. Your awesome